# How to get a OneDriveClient object in java class

Tags: java, android, onedrive

Im Using Onedrive SDK for android .It is working with activity.But how to get a OneDriveClient object in java class?while I am trying on a java class it shows OneDriveClient is null. I am using following link :

[[1]: https://github.com/onedrive/onedrive-sdk-android#23-get-a-onedriveclient-object](https://github.com/onedrive/onedrive-sdk-android#23-get-a-onedriveclient-object)

I dont want place this part in Application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently we are not able to crate using from ordinary java class that using OneDrive SDK. SDK is coupled with Activity for login.